# Makefile is not working on MacOS but on Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, cmake, g++

I am new to CMake and I have the problem where the generated Makefile (based on CMake) is working on Linux and on Windows but on Mac (MacOS Sierra 10.12.6) I get the following errors:

> In file included from /Users/Peter/Documents/Peter/Projects/CGameEngine/C-GameEngine/CGameEngine/src/Engine/Util/Math.cpp:1:
>   In file included from /Users/Peter/Documents/Peter/Projects/CGameEngine/C-GameEngine/CGameEngine/src/Engine/Util/math.h:2:
>   In file included from /Users/Peter/Documents/Peter/Projects/CGameEngine/C-GameEngine/CGameEngine/src/../Dependencies/include/glm/glm.hpp:79:
>   In file included from /Users/Peter/Documents/Peter/Projects/CGameEngine/C-GameEngine/CGameEngine/src/../Dependencies/include/glm/detail/_fixes.hpp:4:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:313:9: error: 
>         no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
>   using ::signbit;
>         ~~^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:314:9: error: 
>         no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
>   using ::fpclassify;
>         ~~^
>   ........
>   fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
>   20 errors generated.
>   make[1](https://github.com/3DExtended/C-GameEngine): *** [src/CMakeFiles/engine.dir/Engine/Util/Math.cpp.o] Error 1
>   make: *** [Engine/Util/Math.cpp.o] Error 2

I am using glm in my project which seems to conflict with the definition of "cmath" and "math.h".

Interesting enough when I try to compile the file (in this case "Math.cpp") using the following command it compiles with no problem:

```
clang -c -I ../../../Dependencies/include/ Math.cpp
```

or this command:

```
g++ -Wall -I../../../Dependencies/include -g -c Math.cpp -o Math.o
```

In result, I think my CMake configuration is wrong.

Those are the two scripts that I am using:

CMake #1 - Project specifications:

```
PROJECT (engine C CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src )
```

CMake #1 - Engine lib specifications:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Dependencies/include)

#when a header only file was programmed we have to add its path as follows
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Util)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Util/Curves)


#add every cpp file to this line
add_library(engine STATIC 
    Engine/Util/FileSystem.cpp 
    Engine/Util/lodepng.cpp 
    Engine/Util/Math.cpp 
    Engine/Util/Rect.cpp 
    Engine/Util/Util.cpp 
    Engine/Util/Generators/CylinderGenerator.cpp
    Engine/Util/Generators/IcosphereGenerator.cpp
    Engine/Util/Generators/PerlinNoise.cpp
    Engine/Camera.cpp
    Engine/Display.cpp
    Engine/Engine.cpp
    Engine/Input.cpp
    Engine/Mesh.cpp
    Engine/Model.cpp
    Engine/Scene.cpp
    Engine/SceneHandler.cpp
    Engine/Shader.cpp
    Engine/Texture.cpp
    Engine/Components/Renderer.cpp
    Engine/ComponentBased/Component.cpp
    Engine/ComponentBased/GameObject.cpp
    Engine/ComponentBased/Transform.cpp
    Engine/GUI/FontHandler.cpp
    Engine/GUI/GUIRenderer.cpp
    Engine/GUI/Text.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(engine lib)
```

When you need more information about the project look at its Github page: [Github](https://github.com/3DExtended/C-GameEngine)

You are required to provide the dependencies yourself if you are cloning this project (see "./.travis.yml" for a working test bench on Linux).

I would appreciate any help and thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: I will not inspect any github pages.

Comment: It looks like it's a known gcc problem of some sort.

Comment: @manni66 Than let me know which information you need and I'll write them to this post.

Comment: @n.m. the same happens when I change the compiler to clang...

Comment: Try making a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)